# Sending multiple images from HTML INPUT tag using AJAX to Laravel Controller along with other data from outside the form

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, laravel

```
$('#modal-save').on('click', function(event){
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: urlEdit,
    data: {
        body: $('#post-body').val(),
        deletePhoto: deletePhoto,
        postId: postId,
         _token: token 
    }
})
.done(function(msg){
    $(postBodyElement).text(msg['new_body']);
    location.reload();
    $('#edit-modal').modal('hide');
});
```

});

What I am trying to do is edit a post. What happens is, an edit modals opens and  previous data and photos are displayed to the user. If the user clicks on the delete button all the photos to that post are deleted.He can edit the text that will be updated in the database. Right now I am sending the data required to do this using ajax. Now I want to insert new photos to the that post. I have a multiple input tag in my html.

```
<input id="post-input" name="photos[]" class="post-input" type="file multiple accept='image/*,video/*' />
```

and my controller function looks something like this

```
 public function postEditPost(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'body' => 'required'
    ]);
    $post = Post::find($request['postId']);
    if (Auth::user() != $post->user){
        return redirect()->back();
    }
    $photos = Photos::where('post_id', $request['postId'])->get();
    $deletePhoto =  $request['deletePhoto'];
    if($deletePhoto == 0){
        foreach($photos as $photo){
            $photo->delete();
        }
    }
  
    $post->body = $request['body'];
    $post->update();
    return response()->json(['new_body' => $post->body],200);
}
```

Comment: https://medium.com/@ldiebold/ajax-file-upload-with-axios-and-laravel-a296bc51f81d

Comment: The two key parts are: headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' }, and document.getElementById("create-game-file").files[0]. Also you will need to use FormData for what you are posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need something like the following:

HTML:

```
<input id="images-input" class="post-input" type="file" multiple accept='image/*' />
```

JS:

```
let data = new FormData();
let input = document.getElementById("images-input");

data.append('body', $('#post-body').val());
data.append('deletePhoto', deletePhoto);
data.append('postId', postId);
data.append('_token', token); 
data.append('images', input.files.map(function (image) {
    return image.file;
});

$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: urlEdit,
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
    data: data,
})
```

Controller:

```
public function postEditPost(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        ...
        'images' => ['nullable', 'array'], // Unless they are mandatory,
        'images.*' => ['image'],
    ]);

    $images = [];
    
    foreach ($request->input('images') as $key => $image) {
        $images[] = $request->file("images.$key");
    }
    ...
}
```

Now you have an array of UploadedFile objects, you can [store them](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#file-uploads) as you wish.